# String.getBytes() does not work on some larger strings in android

Tags: java, string, byte

I am trying to convert a string using String.getBytes("UTF-32"). It works fine for shorter strings. But for longer ones, it truncates and save upto a limit.

I need to convert the string to bytes for printing the text in it. I can see the whole string before converting (before using "string".getbytes), but when it is printed, it print upto a limit.

Any solutions / suggestions guys.

Comment: You'll have to give an example of input and real vs expected output. How long is the string?

Comment: Dear Sotirios Delimanolis, Thank you for the quick reply. This happens when the string length is more than 4700. I have a string with more than 4700 chars. The text is converted to bytes and sent to print. But the printer prints only the first 4700 chars and the rest is ignored / truncated

Comment: Then this doesn't seem to have anything to do with `String`, but rather everything to do with your output device.

Comment: I don't think so. Coz we have a windows PDA which works fine. This happens when getting bytes. Can it be something related to a max size a byte array can hold? or is there a max size for byte array. I tried using the "string".getBytes(0, "string".length + 1, byteArrayObject, 0) as well. But the same result as when I use "String".getBytes("UTF-8").

BTW, "string".getBytes("UF-8") prints less data than "string".getBytes("UTF-32")

Comment: Yes, an array does have a max size, `Integer.MAX_SIZE`. But with a `String` of length 4700, that doesn't even come close.

Comment: I suggest you print the result of `String.getBytes("UTF-32").length`. You will see for yourself that it isn't truncated to 4700. You also seem to be assuming that your printing device understands UTF-32. Does it?

Comment: Dear EPJ, UTF-32 was given just to try. I was using the default encoding. (Since we don't need one as it is plain text in English).

Anyway, I suppose the issue is different and not related to getBytes.

As Stephen explained below, I am redefining my issue. It can be due to output stream that is causing the possible issue. Maybe there is a limit by default.

Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: The question here is: how are you trying to "print" the output? If you're using some sort of debug output on Android you should know that it have a limit for single message length.

Comment: Thanks ForNever for the reply, Any idea about increasing the limit for a single message?

Here is the code for reference.

mBTSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mdevice, 1);
mBTSocket.connect();
OutputStream os = mBTSocket.getOutputStream();
                    byte[] printBytes = printData.getBytes("US-ASCII");
                    if (printBytes != null) {
                        os.write(printBytes);
                    }

                    mBTSocket.close();


I am a bit doubtful about os.write(printBytes); Maybe there is some code to increase the buffer size while sending the data

Comment: @NealGabriel (1) UTF-32 isn't the default encoding. (2) If you're writing to a `Socket` and receiving less data than expected, the problem is bound to be at the receiving end. Post the receiving code. (3) Checking the result of `String.getBytes()` for null is futile. It [doesn't return null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `String.getBytes("UTF-32")` does NOT "truncate" the resulting `byte[]` or the `String`.  Not ever.

You will either get the byte representation of the entire `String` ... or an `OutOfMemoryError`; i.e. a complete failure.

So what is causing the truncation?

- It could be happening before the `getBytes` call; e.g. the process that is reading or creating the string could be truncating it, for some reason.
- It could be happening after the `getBytes` call; e.g. the process that is outputting the `byte[]` (or whatever) could have a line limit.  (For example, I recall that `logcat` has a limit on the length of log messages ... and the number `4700` is vaguely familiar.)

Without seeing your code, and the evidence for the truncation, it is impossible to be certain what is actually going on here.  But we can say with confidence that it is NOT `getBytes` that is doing the truncation.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I agree with you. Then the possible issue could be on the bluetooth socket. Here is the code.

OutputStream os = mBTSocket.getOutputStream();
byte[] printBytes = printData.getBytes("US-ASCII");

if (printBytes != null) {
                        os.write(printBytes);
                    }

Comment: Nope.  That's not the problem.  The `write` operations on an `OutputStream` do not truncate either.  (If they can't write all of the bytes requested, they will throw an exception.)  But you are only guessing here, and that is not sound debugging technique.  Be **methodical**.  Find  out what the length of `printBytes` really is.  Also, if you want to find out how a method is going to behave, READ THE JAVADOCS.

Comment: I totally agree with you Stephen. I may need to improve my findings and debugging technique. Thanks for your support.